# Apex Link builder value - item not displayed on the target page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I LOAD P70_NODE_ID from Javascript.

APEX 20.2

then run the following:

1. apex_util.set_session_state('P70_NODE_ID_OUT', :P70_NODE_ID);

When I show the session I see P70_NODE_ID_OUT  and P70_NODE_ID. They both have the correct values

2. link to another page using the link builder

under item and value:
item P80_STEP_ID value :P70_NODE_ID_OUT

3. display p80_STEP_ID

I never see a value.

NOTE: The target page is a modal dialog built with the form wizard.

I have tried using a where statement P80_STEP_ID = :P70_NODE_ID_OUT

Still I don't see a value.

Is the problem related to inserting a value from Javascript?

How do I work around this?

Thanks

Comment: You mention "inserting a value from Javascript" but nothing you've said suggests you're using Javascript here. Is there something else your page is doing that you're not telling us?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when using redirect to another page in the same application, it uses the values that exist when the page is built and never looks at the values again. As a result, when values change after a page is loaded, the new values aren't used. The following allows you to use changed values when redirecting.

Used advice from the Apex community. This is what worked for me.

This uses apex_page.get_url and the technique you suggested. Tested good.

Javascript that runs when a node is selected in a flowchart:

```
$s('P72_NODE_ID', tagNum);
$s('P72_NODE_TYPE', selNode.getShape().getId());
$.event.trigger('submitNodeSel');
```

DynamicEvent

WHEN

event: custom

custom event: submitNodeSel

selectionType: javascriptexpression

javascript expression: document

True Action

Action: set value

set type: PL/SQL Function Body

```
DECLARE

STEP_DETAIL_URL varchar2(2000);

l_app number := v('APP_ID');

l_session number := v('APP_SESSION');
BEGIN   

STEP_DETAIL_URL :=  apex_page.get_url(

  p_page => '80'

, p_items => 'p80_step_id,p80_node_type'

, p_values => :p72_node_id || ',' || :p72_node_type

, p_plain_url => true); 



RETURN STEP_DETAIL_URL;

END;
```

input: p72_node_id,p72_node_type

affected Elements

selection type: item(s)

item(s): P72_STEP_DETAIL_URL

BUTTON

Dynamic Action

execute javascript code

True Action

Javascript

```
makeDialogUrl( $v("P72_STEP_DETAIL_URL"));
```

Javascript Code

```
function makeDialogUrl (url) {
    var i;
    // replace unicode escapes
    url = url.replace(/\\u(\d\d\d\d)/g, function(m,d) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(d, 16));
    });
apex.navigation.dialog(url,
{title:'Dialog In 
Out',height:'auto',width:'720',maxWidth:'960',modal:true,dialog:null},
"t-Dialog-page--standard", "#STEP_DETAILS");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**2** should be

2. under item and value: item `P80_STEP_ID` value `&P70_NODE_ID_OUT.`

Note leading ampersand `&` and trailing dot `.`

BTW, Apex would have done it for you if you picked columns from the LoV.

Comment: Sorry I missed the & and period. Tried it, still no help.

Comment: Then you did something wrong, because that **is** the way to do it. If possible, create an example on apex.oracle.com, provide developer credentials so that someone of us might have a look and, possibly, help.

Comment: Ok I am going to simplify and test. Maybe something is going on in the background. If that doesn't work, I will do as you suggest. Thanks

Comment: When I submit the page, then navigate to another page things work fine. The problem is that the submit reloads the complex flowchart written by Javascript. The user looses information like what node he selected. Is there a way to submit without refreshing the page? Or only refresh the region that contains the node_id item? Can I use the set session utility?

Comment: https://c77boasnxzxyszt-db202104292101.adb.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/f?p=4550:1:10424277438294:::::

Comment: workspace: AKLDEV username: developer  password: ThisIsStrong!01

Comment: I created a simplified project that demonstrates the problem. Please use the above link and login info to see it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I tried to make it work without submitting the page, but - unfortunately - failed :( It looks as if P1_EMP_ID item's "Source - used" property should be "Always, replacing any existing value in session state", but that passes *nothing* to Page 2. Frustrating.

Comment: Are you part of the Oracle Apex team? What do you suggest I do next? Should I put this on the APEX blog?  Thanks

Comment: I'm just an ordinary Apex user. What to do? See OTN Forums, Apex *authors* visit it and you might get the answer there. If you do, please, post a link to that discussion here, I'm really interested in solution.

Comment: Here is the link. Also see the answer I provided. https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4483958/how-to-redirect-using-dynamic-actions#latest

Comment: I see; fac586 assisted. Great, I'm glad you made it work! Thank you for letting us know!